# \mode<presentation> between two frames in beamerarticle

Tags: beamer, presentations, beamerarticle

There is a minimal code of what I want to do :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
text 1
\mode<presentation>{
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
}
text 2
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I get the following error :

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
```

In my mind, I thought it would the same than :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
text 1
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
text 2
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

EDIT :
I want to have a document and a presentation.
The document works well :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{block}{Block title}
        text1\newline
        \uncover<2->{text2}\newline
        text3\newline
\mode<presentation>{
    \end{block}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{block}
}
        \noindent text4\newline
        \uncover<2->{text5}\newline
        text6\newline
    \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But the presentation doesn't :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{block}{Block title}
        text1\newline
        \uncover<2->{text2}\newline
        text3\newline
\mode<presentation>{
    \end{block}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{block}
}
        \noindent text4\newline
        \uncover<2->{text5}\newline
        text6\newline
    \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I don't want to use [allowframebreaks] because the \uncover command doesn't works with...

I don't want to create two blocks because it will create two blocks in the document

I want all the text in one block for the document and half the text in one block in the presentation and half the text in one other block on one other frame... This in order to be able to use \uncover command

Comment: Your mode is crossing `frame` boundaries (not in tune with `begin` and `end`).

Comment: By far the simplest way will be to just include the material for this part twice: once in the scope of \mode<article> and once in the scope of \mode<presentation> with the blocks set up as you wish.

Comment: @cfr : by doing that, I loose the interest of beamerarticle.

Comment: @kara Well, as jon pointed out, your mode specification can't cross frame boundaries in that way. So you may need to modify your requirements ;).