# Break block between two frames in presentation but not in article mode

Tags: beamer, beamerarticle

I am confronted to a long-proof problem like in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66532/proofs-in-beamer), which entails breaking a block between two frames, and also to the problem that I am creating an article and I do not want the proof environment to be broken there, like in [that closed question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153395/).

How can I combine both ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a more elegant solution, using lua to hide the frame-splitting code from LaTeX in article mode.

```latex
\RequirePackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode*}
envname = ""
current = ""

function startGobble(cur, fut)
  envname = fut
  current = cur
  luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", gobble, "gobbler")
end

function gobble(line)
  if line:find("\\begin{"..envname.."}") ~= nil then
    luatexbase.remove_from_callback("process_input_buffer", "gobbler")
    luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", replace, "replacer")
    return "\\refstepcounter{framenumber}"
  else
    return ""
  end
end

function replace(line)
  if line:find("\\end{"..envname.."}") ~= nil then
    luatexbase.remove_from_callback("process_input_buffer", "replacer")
    return line:gsub("\\end{"..envname.."}", "\\end{"..current.."}")
  else
    return line
  end
end    
\end{luacode*}


\mode
<presentation>
\NewDocumentCommand{\mergeFrame}{mm}{}

\mode
<article>
\NewDocumentCommand{\mergeFrame}{mm}{\luadirect{startGobble("#1", "#2");}}

\mode
<all>
```

We can then say

```latex
\NewDocumentEnvironment{preuve}{O{Preuve}}{\begin{block}{#1}}{\end{block}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{alertblock}{Berge, 1957}
Un couplage $C$ est de cardinal maximal si et seulement s'il n'admet pas de chemin augmentant.
\end{alertblock}
\pause
\begin{preuve}[Preuve du sens non couvert par le lemme]
some already long text
\mergeFrame{preuve}{block}
\end{preuve}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{}

Soit $p$ un chemin maximal dans $K$ : \uncover<2->{sa première et sa dernière arêtes sont dans $C_2$.}
\end{block}

Remarque : ce lemme et ce théorème n'utilisent pas le fait que le graphe est biparti.\\
Cette propriété va cependant permettre de faciliter la recherche d'un chemin augmentant.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

In presentation mode, the `\mergeFrame` does nothing. In article mode, it sets up a line-gobbler until it sees `\begin{block}` (included). It then lets the content show up, until it sees `\end{block}`, which it replaces with `\end{preuve}`. Therefore, in article mode, LaTeX saw a single `preuve` environment. We `\refstepcounter{framenumber}` when going out from gobbling mode, although this should not be very relevant in article mode.

Answer (score 1):

After fumbling with the different versions of `\mode`, I managed to get it to work.

I do not really understand why I have to use one version at some place and the other at another place, and I am open to explanations, better ways of doing it or even automating it (ie. defining a shorter macro to do that).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
\@ifclassloaded{beamer}{\usecolortheme{orchid}}{\usepackage{beamerarticle}}
\makeatother

\NewDocumentEnvironment{preuve}{O{Preuve}}{\begin{block}{#1}}{\end{block}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{alertblock}{Berge, 1957}
Un couplage $C$ est de cardinal maximal si et seulement s'il n'admet pas de chemin augmentant.
\end{alertblock}
\pause
\begin{preuve}[Preuve du sens non couvert par le lemme]
some already long text

\mode
<presentation>
% article mode does not see this
\hfill …/…
\end{preuve}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{}

\mode
<all>
Soit $p$ un chemin maximal dans $K$ : \uncover<2->{sa première et sa dernière arêtes sont dans $C_2$.}
\mode
<presentation>
\end{block}\pause[3]\vfill

\mode
<all>

\mode<article>{\end{preuve}}

Remarque : ce lemme et ce théorème n'utilisent pas le fait que le graphe est biparti.\\
Cette propriété va cependant permettre de faciliter la recherche d'un chemin augmentant.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Beamer blocks are -- by default -- not breakable. However you can replace them by breakable tcolorboxes and use `\framebreak` to break your block as you like.

The `\framebreak` macro is defined to only act in presentation mode, thus it won't interfere with your article.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\@ifclassloaded{beamer}{\usecolortheme{orchid}}{\usepackage{beamerarticle}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\useinnertheme{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{breakable,title after break=\insertblocktitle}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\begin{proof}
\lipsum[1]
\framebreak
\lipsum[1]
\end{proof}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, but you cannot have ``\pause`` in a tcolorbox, afaik.